# JasperStudio count rows for group

Tags: jasper-reports

I just installed JasperStudio and have been struggling with the following group report, can't find how to make this work using variables or any other method:

```
"Group A"  /  Entries: <$V{count_g1}>
    |
    --- "Group B" / Entries: <$V{count_g2}>
          |
          --- "Group C" / Entries: <$V{count_g3}>
                  |
                  --- "Group D" / Entries: <$V{count_g4}>
                         |
                         --- "Group E" / Entries: <$V{count_g5}>
                                |
                                [Detail Band]
                                ID      Name       Surname      Email
```

I need to display the number of records for each group by counting the "ID" field.

Tried various "expressions" when creating the variable , but I am obviously doing something wrong because I either get "null" or 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, Jasper doesn't support (bug or by design?) aggregate functions/variables in header bands.

If I move the same variables/fields to the footer bands , then they are all perfectly displayed.